# Android equivalent of dispatch_once (Objective-C)

Tags: java, android

I want to know the equivalent of `dispatch_once` in Android to fire the `Intent` exactly once.

Comment: The alternative would be AsyncTask.

Comment: @eric247: dispatch_once and AsyncTask is two different mechanism. dispatch_async and AsyncTask are for the same purpose

Comment: An Asynctask can only be executed once, if you try to run it a second time it will throw an exception, but if you create a new instance of Asynctask, it will be executed again. Two possible approaches come to my mind: to keep the instance of the Asynctask and execute the execute() on that instance, so the second time you call execute() will throw you the exception which you have to control, or implement a variable to control that you don't run the thread a second time, more likely it is implemented in dispatch_once

Comment: This should not be tagged objective-c, nor as ios.

Answer (score 1):

simply use AtomicInteger:

```
static AtomicInteger predicate = new AtomicInteger();

void SomeFunction() {
      if (predicate.getAndIncrement()==0) {
          System.out.println("Print once");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DispatchOnce {

public static class Token {
    private boolean hasRun = false;
}

private DispatchOnce(){}

public static synchronized void run(Token token, Runnable runnable) {
    if (!token.hasRun) {
        token.hasRun = true;
        runnable.run();
    }
}
}
```

Sample usage

```
public static DispatchOnce.Token MY_DISPATCH_ONCE_TOKEN = new DispatchOnce.Token();

public void example() {
    DispatchOnce.run(MY_DISPATCH_ONCE_TOKEN, () -> {
        System.out.println("Print once");
    });
}
```